# Regex: Check incoming uri is present in list

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I am trying to write a regex to check whether the incoming url path is matches with any of my list elements.How can I write that?. I tried to use `String.contains(/api/v1/read)` but it returns false even though it is present in list.

```
my path : /api/v1/read

List<String> pathList = {"/api/v1/**,/api/v2/**"};
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you only need to support the `/**` wildcard, or do you also need to support other types of wildcards?

Answer (score 1):

If the only wildcard you need to support is a path ending in `/**`, then you'd do it as follows:

1. Split any comma-separated string into separate paths:

   `{ "/api/v1/**,/api/v2/**", "/api/foo.ico" }`
   → `{ "/api/v1/**", "/api/v2/**", "/api/foo.ico" }`
2. Convert each path to a regex:

   - If path doesn't end in `/**`, just quote it by calling `Pattern.quote(path)`<sup>1</sup>:

     `"/api/foo.ico"` → `"\\Q/api/foo.ico\\E"`
   - If path ends in `/**`, quote everything except `**` and replace that with `.*`:

     `"/api/v1/**"` → `"\\Q/api/v1/\\E.*"`
     `"/api/v2/**"` → `"\\Q/api/v2/\\E.*"`
3. Combine all the path regex's using the `|` OR pattern:

   → `"\\Q/api/v1/\\E.*|\\Q/api/v2/\\E.*|\\Q/api/foo.ico\\E"`
4. Compile the regex and use the `matcher.matches()` method to check incoming path.

<sup>*1) `Pattern.quote()` will surround the text with `\Q` and `\E`, and correctly handle any embedded `\E` pairs.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by regular expressions.

```
public static void main(final String strg[]) {
        String pattern= "/api/(v1|v2)/.*";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher("/api/v1/read");
        if(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("match found");
        }
    }
```

Instead of adding each possibility of URI into a list, add them into the regular expression to create a pattern.

Comment: If you use `find()`, you need to use regex `"^/api/(v1|v2)/"`. If you want to use the regex in the answer, you need to use `matches()`.